# Android Capture image with filename

Tags: android

this is my first day on android and i would like to make an app that will capture an image and the image name will output at the variable and textbox under the ImageView.

This is my code now and capture image is functioning. What i need to do next is to get the file name and filepath. Thanks. I tried to find but i dont know where to put the codes.

```
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class Create extends ActionBarActivity {

    Button capImg;
    int requestcode = 1;
    ImageView imgView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_create);
        capImg = (Button)findViewById(R.id.capImg);
        imgView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imgView);

        capImg.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0){
                Intent i = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                if(i.resolveActivity(getPackageManager())!=null){
                    startActivityForResult(i, requestcode);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.create, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultcode, Intent data){
        if(requestCode==requestcode){
            if(resultcode==RESULT_OK){
                Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                bundle = data.getExtras();
                Bitmap BMP;
                BMP = (Bitmap)bundle.get("data");
                imgView.setImageBitmap(BMP);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To save a picture Add a fileUri to the intent.

```
private Uri fileUri;

fileUri = getOutputMediaFileUri(MEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO);  // create a file to save the video
intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, fileUri);  // set the image file name
```

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera.html

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
if (requestCode == CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE) {
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        // Image captured and saved to fileUri specified in the Intent
        Toast.makeText(this, "Image saved to:\n" +
                 data.getData(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
        // User cancelled the image capture
    } else {
        // Image capture failed, advise user
    }
}
```